# Extract superpixels, retrieve edges and reduce mesh

Tags: python, mesh, shapely, scikit-image, rasterio

How would one extract superpixels, retrieve edges then simplify those?
This is what I've gotten so far:

```
import skimage
import numpy as np
from rasterio import features
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

image = skimage.util.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread("image.jpg"))
labels = skimage.segmentation.slic(image, n_segments = 200, sigma = 5)
boundaries = skimage.segmentation.find_boundaries(labels).astype(np.uint8)

#this is where it goes wrong as rasterio creates shapes with distinct edges
shapes = rasterio.features.shapes(boundaries)

polygons = MultiPolygon([Polygon(sh[0]["coordinates"][0]) for sh in shapes])
out = polygons.simplify(0.05)
```

The problem here is that the simplification works on a per polygon basis and therefore its output isn't a tight mesh.

I'm looking to achieve something similar to [this](https://www.vis4.net/blog/posts/simplification-of-country-outlines/), so obtaining the edges and being able to simplify.

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Comment: @langkilde hmm, i can't actually seem to remember, but i don't think i did, please share if you manage to!